# Como prevenir um event listener globalmente?

Tags: javascript, react, event-listener

criei um event listener em App.js com o seguinte:

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("scroll", e => {
    scrollToSection_DataLayer('#section1');
    scrollToSection_DataLayer('#section2');
  });
}, []);
```

Essas são funções externas que são executadas ao dar *scroll* (comportamento esperado).
Porém, em outro arquivo, possuo anchors que provocam o scroll da landing-page e logicamente disparam as funções do useEffect acima. Mas eu não gostaria que isso acontecesse. Há alguma forma de eu prevenir por um tempo, de **fora** do App.js, que essas funções do useEffect que estão no App.js não sejam disparadas ao clicar nos anchors?

Comment: Como está organizado o seu código? existe sim a forma de remover eventos, mas, só com esse trecho de código pode ficar incompleta a resposta, então, como estão os componentes exemplifique com um exemplo minimo.

Comment: Valeu pela resposta rápida. Cara, está componentizado em compartimento. Há meu Index.js que inicia a seleção da root do documento pra inserir App.js e App.js importa as seções que importas componentes reutilizáveis. Com isso ajuda?

Comment: Coloca na pergunta e um exemplo dos componentes!